# Set environment variables for non-interactive ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, proxy, environment-variables

Where is the most appropriate place to set environment variables for all (including non-interactive) ssh sessions, and for all users (including root)?

I believe that it may be in a script under `/etc/profile.d/`, but I'm not confident that making a change there won't adversely affect something else in my configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `sshd(8)` man page, **FILES** section:

```
 ~/.ssh/environment
         This file is read into the environment at login (if it exists).
         It can only contain empty lines, comment lines (that start with
         ‘#’), and assignment lines of the form name=value.  The file
         should be writable only by the user; it need not be readable by
         anyone else.  Environment processing is disabled by default and
         is controlled via the PermitUserEnvironment option.
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that only set it for the one user?

Comment: Sure, but there are other options. See the `sshd(8)` man page for details.

Answer (score 2):

In sshd_config, you could set e.g.

```
ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/setsshenv
```

where `setsshenv` looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export VAR1=value1
export VAR2=value2
...
exec $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

I'm not sure if this would run before or after users' ~/.ssh/environment scripts were read.